# MySQL: Multiple AND queries with using BETWEEN?

Tags: php, mysql, between

I had seen a colleague use this to fetch users from a table under these conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender ='male' 
AND activated='yes' 
AND date_registered BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
```

He said there was an problem (it not outputting any rows when the `AND activated='yes'` was put there as well, but no MySQL error was thrown.

Can you not do this? Do you need to put it in brackets or something crazy to associate the `BETWEEN` and `AND`?

Dates are in correct format by the way.

Comment: My first guess is that no rows matched the query in that case...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, it will work just fine.  However, you might want to format your query so it is clear which `AND` is standalone, and which belongs to a `BETWEEN .. AND ...` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE gender ='male' 
   AND activated='yes' 
   AND date_registered BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
```

Comment: I will mention that to him for further tasks, I'll accept your answer after I get back from work, I need to go!

Answer (score 4):

No brackets required. You've got the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks you, that makes it easier to explain.